# how do I test if overfitting exists when I use cross_val_score method?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees, xgboost, cross-validation, accuracy

I got the following code form a book on xgboost.
I wonder whether this is a correct way of analyzing cross validation score for overfitting purposes.
mean accuracy is 81 which can be okay. but what if the training accuracy is 99% ?
Shouldn't we also observe the training accuracy ?
If yes, how can I do it since the model is fitted by the cross_val_score method with 5 difference cross validation-training sets ?

> model = XGBClassifier(booster='gbtree', objective='binary:logistic',
> random_state=2) scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)
> print('Accuracy:', np.round(scores, 2)) print('Accuracy mean: %0.2f' %
> (scores.mean())) Accuracy: [0.85 0.85 0.77 0.78 0.77] Accuracy mean:
> 0.81

Answer (score 2):

Try using `cross_validate` instead of `cross_val_score`, you need to set the parameter `return_train_scorebool=True`

You can refer to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate) if you require further customization:

Comment: thank you for the response. I will try that! I can not upvote it as I am short of reputation points for doing so.

Comment: thanks.. I hope this will help!